# APIgateway + Lamba Test works, but deployed API leads to Lambda timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function behind an APIgateway. I am using proxy integration. So when I use the test function of the APIgateway I get a proper response and a 200 status.
When I use the test function of the Lambda (I use the predefined *Amazon API Gateway AWS Proxy* testevent) everything is fine and I get a 200 status and the correct result.

However, if I stage the API and then try to access it that way I will get a *"Endpoint request timed out"* or *"Internal server error"* depending on my timeout for lambda. Reading the logs I can clearly tell, that the lambda function itself will timeout.

My timeout for the lambda function is usually set to 20 seconds.
If I set it higher, my lambda function will continue working for abaout five minutes and then exit without an error. Sadly I cant see the result, since APIgateway will always timeout after at most 29 seconds.

I can only guess that there is a difference betwen the request sent by *APIgateway tester* / *lambda tester* and the request sent by the *stage*.

Can someone please enlighten me?

APIgateway execution log:

```
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Method request path:
{}
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Method request query string:
{}
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Method request headers: {Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8, CloudFront-Viewer-Country=DE, CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer=false, CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer=false, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer=false, Host=l71vxfeqi.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, X-Forwarded-Port=443, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5d15f634-d96c0d0f39695f7884dc7c57, Via=2.0 7d0bc7cb3b35ca4f488e655fac219221.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), upgrade-insecure-requests=1, X-Amz-Cf-Id=mNIru4JjDjvndC-EbUKTuR60b9CD_uHeG1hRrxLUTLOd0t5hzTqhJw==, X-Forwarded-For=139.2.1.6, 54.182.239.89, Accept-Language=de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3, cache-control=max-age=0, CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer=true}
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Method request body before transformations:
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:908548826170:function:funAsOne/invocations
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d, Authorization=***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************553a6e, X-Amz-Date=20190628T111252Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=l71vxfeqi, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:908548826170:l71vxfeqi/default/ANY/, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_lv17xt01qi, X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBIaDGV1LWNlbnRyYWwtMSJGMEQCIHy9md2iHdQ4EPQmHT9oIzMPljYjRuq7Hq1nWoUhnvgSAiAaaLSRs3v9FJUy1Wl2JhvIe83prHLLwKMKa4mnmVqlASrgAwhbEAAaDDQ3NDI0MDE0NjgwMiIM+FTGP/2q6hBh6HPPKr0D4KW+TSQlaJc4SASsly2jRPCqB5lWlsjmz3WivjwAVtItPVIgUZFrW8uH7tijfkQ4VaQQ3AM32Ilim35r9lgpEnPvsSIcj56k8n+8uPJko5cPQDXjFpFBLkUu5Eq9mjS0KiBEeau0yXk05uy9RQajA4zsF0tir3QHuWMrEblq [TRUNCATED]
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Endpoint request body after transformations: {"resource":"/","path":"/","httpMethod":"GET","headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","Accept-Language":"de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3","cache-control":"max-age=0","CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto":"https","CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer":"true","CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer":"false","CloudFront-Viewer-Country":"DE","Host":"l71vxfeqi.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0","Via":"2.0 7d0bc7cb3b35ca4f488e655fac219221.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)","X-Amz-Cf-Id":"mNIru4JjDjvndC-EbUKTuR60b9CD_uHeG1hRrxLUTLOd0t5hzTqhJw==","X-Amzn-Trace-Id":"Root=1-5d15f634-d96c0d0f39695f7884dc7c57","X-Forwarded-For":"139.2.1.6, 54.182.239.89","X-Forwarded-Port":"443","X-Forwarded-Proto":"https"},"multiValueHeaders":{"A [TRUNCATED]
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Sending request to https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:908548826170:function:funAsOne/invocations
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Received response. Status: 200, Integration latency: 20045 ms
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Endpoint response headers: {Date=Fri, 28 Jun 2019 11:13:12 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=115, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=2061f183-3415-4508-b95e-92d2cefffe6b, X-Amz-Function-Error=Unhandled, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5d15f634-d96c0d0f39695f7884dc7c57;sampled=0}
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Endpoint response body before transformations:
{
    "errorMessage": "2019-06-28T11:13:12.843Z 2061f183-3415-4508-b95e-92d2cefffe6b Task timed out after 20.02 seconds"
}
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: 2019-06-28T11:13:12.843Z 2061f183-3415-4508-b95e-92d2cefffe6b Task timed out after 20.02 seconds. Lambda request id: 2061f183-3415-4508-b95e-92d2cefffe6b
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Gateway response type: DEFAULT_5XX with status code: 502
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Gateway response body:
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Gateway response headers: {Access-Control-Allow-Headers=Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Access-Control-Allow-Methods=DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT}
(ac186ee6-9995-11e9-aa08-19c69016a70d) Method completed with status: 502
```

Lambda execution log:

```
11:19:07 START RequestId: d3a4cfd5-2e8f-489d-a5a3-9601adf406a8 Version: $LATEST
11:19:09 [Fri Jun 28 11:19:09 2019] 127.0.0.1:59760 [301]: /
11:23:48 END RequestId: d3a4cfd5-2e8f-489d-a5a3-9601adf406a8
11:23:48 REPORT RequestId: d3a4cfd5-2e8f-489d-a5a3-9601adf406a8 Init Duration: 73.73 ms Duration: 281070.57 ms Billed Duration: 281200 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 55 MB
```

**I fixed it:**

This behaviour was due to a redirect loop from "home" to "home".

Adding the following line to wp-setting.php fixed it for me. Sadly this is only a workaround. Maybe someone can hint me to a better fix.

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Comment: Is the Lambda function in a VPC? My guess is that the cold start time for the Lambda function is causing the intermittent issue. Do subsequent invocations work?

Comment: What about the test result if you test your lambda by sending apigateway event in lambda console?

Comment: @Kane The same thing as if I would just sent a testrequest vie APIgateway. It just works fine.

Comment: @jmp Subsequent  invocations will be just as slow as the ones before them. (even if I wait for the first Lambda execution to finish)

Comment: API Gateway has 60s timeout limit. Looks like your lambda was running quite slow. You might add more verbose log to trace what's going wrong or use APM SaaS to trace it.